# Shell script to parallely execute a command remotely on N systems

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, automation

How to execute a command remotely on N systems in parallel via shell script? The command is `yum -y update`

Comment: `salt-ssh n-systems-pattern pkg.upgrade` as in https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.yumpkg.html

Comment: I know how to do it via config tools like ansible, chef, salt. looking for a solution via shell scripting.

Comment: Try GNU parallel: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#GNU-Parallel-Tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Parallel has a function for that:

```
N=10
parallel -j$N --nonall -S server1,server2,server3 yum -y update
```

The servers can also be read from a file:

```
N=10
parallel -j$N --nonall --slf hostfile yum -y update
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically I will do that:

```sh
for SRV in srv1 srv2 srv3
do
    ssh ${SRV} "yum -y update" &
done
wait
```

It will start the command on each servers and wait for everything to finish.

You should consider to add the different `srv` in your `.ssh/config` and use a public key authentication on each servers.

Comment: You may also want to add some sophistication to prevent running too many concurrent operations.

Comment: @jml thanks for your reply. do you think above script can go in hung state under any scenario ?

Comment: It's not likely to hang (unless the SSH connection is spotty), but it will be difficult to triage errors.

Comment: @Aty Yes the `wait` means that *all currently active child processes are waited for* (cf [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)). But this is a **basic** approach, so you may have issues (output filtering, too many concurrent operations...)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [Cluster SSH](https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-multiple-linux-servers-clusterssh). It´s a simple way to execute the same things in a number of machines. Follow the link to view a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking for a shell script not a tool.

Comment: @Aty why? Are you trying to solve a problem, or just play with Bash scripts?

Comment: @dimo414 Its pretty easy to execute a command remote on N systems in a sequential manner via shell script but this takes a lot of time to complete as are tasks are executed sequentially on each system. Looking for way to address this problem via shell script.

Comment: Shell scripts often aren't the best solution to a problem. The reason more powerful tools exist is exactly because building your own in a shell language is error-prone. If using a proper deployment tool is too much overhead, managing a shell script that runs *n* remote commands in parallel is going to be even more of a hassle.

Comment: Sequential execution: for system in `filename`; do ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l loginID -t $system "command";done